# How does the compiler treats printing unsigned int as signed int?

Tags: c, printing, unsigned-integer

I'm trying to figure out why the following code:

```
{
  unsigned int a = 10;
  a = ~a;
  printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

`a` will be `00001010` to begin with, and after NOT opertaion, will transform

into `11110101`.

What happens exactly when one tries to print `a` as signed integer, that makes

the printed result to be `-11`?

I thought i would end up seeing `-5` maybe (according to the binary representation), but not `-11`.

I'll be glad to get a clarification on the matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2's complement notation is used to store negative numbers.

The number 10 is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010 in 4 byte binary.

a=~a makes the content of a as 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101.

This number when treated as signed int will tell the compiler to 
take the most significant bit as sign and rest as magnitude.

The 1 in the msb makes the number a negative number.

Hence 2's complement operation is performed on the remaining bits.

Thus 111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101 becomes 
000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1011.

This when interpreted as a decimal integer becomes -11.

Comment: Pedantic comment: C doesn't require 2s complement. It doesn't even specify how numbers are stored. x86 and ARM though, use 2s complement

Answer (score 2):

When you write `a = ~a;` you reverse each an every bit in a, what is also called a complement to 1.

The representation of a negative number is declared as *implementation dependant*, meaning that different architectures could have different representation for `-10` or `-11`.

Assuming a 32 architecture on a common processor that uses complement to 2 to represent negative numbers -1 will be represented as FFFFFFFF (hexadecimal) or 32 bits to 1.

`~a` will be represented as = `FFFFFFF5` or in binary `1...10101` which is the representation of -11.

Nota: the first part is always the same and is not implementation dependant, `~a` **is** `FFFFFFF5` on any 32 bits architecture. It is only the second part (-11 == `FFFFFFF5`) that is implementation dependant. BTW it would be -10 on an architecture that would use complement to 1 to represent negative numbers.